# Terraform doesn't add log group name on cloudwatch event target

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch

I create a rule in `Cloudwatch` and attach a `log group` as its target in `Terraform`.

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "trigger_glue_job_lambda" {
  rule = "${aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.crawler.name}"
  target_id = "SendToLambda"
  arn = "${aws_lambda_function.trigger_glue_job.arn}"
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "log_glue_crawler_result" {
  rule = "${aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.crawler.name}"
  target_id = "LogCrawler"
  arn = "${aws_cloudwatch_log_group.grue_crawler_log_group.arn}"
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "grue_crawler_log_group" {
  name = "crawler_log"
  tags = {
    Application = "reddit_movies"
  }
}
```

You see the above configuration includes a `log group` resource definition and two `event target`, one for log group the other is for triggering a lambda. Below is the screenshot of this configuration in aws cloudwatch rule console.

[image]

You see the target in the bottom of the screenshot shows lambda correctly but it doesn't show the name of the log group I created. Instead, it shows a `*` for the log group name. I wonder what wrong with my configuration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After checking the value of the [arn](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudwatch_log_group.html#arn) attribute of cloudwatch log group, for some reason it is appending an asterisk at the end in this format format `arn:aws:logs:eu-west-1:12345678912:log-group:crawler_log:*`
Change your code like this to remove the last 2 characters:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "log_glue_crawler_result" {
  rule = "${aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.crawler.name}"  
  target_id = "LogCrawler"
  arn = "${substr(aws_cloudwatch_log_group.grue_crawler_log_group.arn,0,length(aws_cloudwatch_log_group.grue_crawler_log_group.arn) - 2)}"
}
```

Comment: Is it a bug in terraform?

Comment: How did you check the `arn` attribute?

Comment: Well spotted @WalidK. Just to add some info on this: it is not terraform who adds the trailing chars but AWS itself. If you describe the ARNs of a log group, it already has the `:*` at the end. The question is why the aws_cloudwatch_event_target doesn't take this into account :/